# Exim: forward mail for subdomains to main domain MX

Tags: exim

I've got a domain (`example.com`) registered with Google Apps, and have their mailservers registered as the MX record for my domain. I also have a site with a central mailserver (Exim4 on Ubuntu), and a number of other servers. Each server is set to use this mailserver as a smarthost for outgoing mail.

The issue I have is that when a server sends mail to an address of the format `user@hostname.example.com` (e.g. when a cronjob fails), the mailserver doesn't know what to do with it. It tries to make an SMTP connection directly to `hostname.exmple.com`, which fails.

How would I configure exim so that it knows to deliver `@*.example.com` to the MX record for `example.com`?

Answer (score 0):

In DNS for your zone, create an MX record for hostname.example.com, pointed to the same hostname that example.com MX is pointed to.

Or configure your various servers to send mail from *@example.com instead of *@hostname.example.com.